# Special flowchart drawing

Tags: flow-charts

I need following flowchart in my paper.
how can i draw it?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. There are several ways to achieve such a chat. I'd start with tikz flowchart. Also tikz circuits could help. Look them up...

Comment: thanks. But I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: thanks dear.
I am trying for it, and will send the result as soon as I can. So I hope to have your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of trying and, of course, searching the internet, I almost found the answer to my question and I will upload it here for the use of the other members. Special thanks to DG' for motivating me to work harder and become more familiar with latex software. I believe that without suffering treasure would not be possible and I see it with my eyes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning, fit}
\usepackage{caption}
\tikzset{process5/.style={rectangle,
      draw=blue,
      thick,
      fill=blue!30,
      text width=4em,
      align=center,
      rounded corners,
      minimum height=3em}}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\tikzset{process6/.style={rectangle,
      draw=red,
      thick,
      fill=red!10,
      text width=4em,
      align=center,
      rounded corners,
      minimum height=3em}}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
\node(S) [process5]{S };
\node(E) [process5, below of=S, yshift=-1.5cm]{E};
\node(I_2) [process5, below of=E,yshift=-1.5cm]{$I_2$};
\node(I_1) [process5, right of=I_2,xshift=3cm]{$I_1$};
\node(R) [process5, below of=I_2,yshift=-1.0cm]{R};
\coordinate[above of =S] (out);
\coordinate[right of =S] (in);

                            %%% S<--->E%%%
\draw [arrow] ([xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-1.05cm] S.north) -- ([xshift=0.3cm,yshift=1.05cm]  
E.south) node [pos=0.5,right] {$\frac{\alpha_3 SI_2}{N}$};
\draw [arrow] ([xshift=-0.3cm]E.north) -- ([xshift=-0.3cm]S.south) node [pos=0.5,  
left] {$\beta_1 E$};
                            %%% S --->I_1%%%
\draw[black,arrow] let \p1=(S), \p2=(I_1) in (S) -- (4,0)  -- (4,-4)-- 
([yshift=-0.05cm]I_1.north) node [pos=-3.5,right] {$\frac{\alpha_1 SI_1}{N}$};
                            %%% S <--->I_2%%%
\draw[black,arrow] let \p1=(S), \p2=(I_2) in (S)[xshift=0.5cm, yshift=0.1cm] -- 
(2,-0.5)-- (2,-4.7) node [pos=0.45,right] {$\frac{\alpha_2 SI_2}{N}$}-- 
([xshift=0.8cm,yshift=-0.25cm]I_2.north) ;
\draw[black,arrow] let \p1=(I_2), \p2=(S) in (I_2) -- (-1.5,-5)  -- (-1.5,-0.3) node 
[pos=0.35,left] {$\theta_2 I_2$}-- ([yshift=-0.3cm]S.west);
                            %%% E--->I_2%%%
\draw [arrow] (E) -- (I_2) node [pos=0.5, right] {$\beta_2 E$};
                            %%% I_1--->I_2%%%
\draw [arrow] (I_1)-- (I_2) node [pos=0.5, below] {$\gamma_2 I_1$};
                            %%% I_2<--->R%%%
\draw [arrow] ([xshift=0.3cm,yshift=-1.05cm] I_2.north) -- 
([xshift=0.3cm,yshift=1.05cm]  R.south) node [pos=0.5,right] {$\theta_1 I_2$};
\draw [arrow] ([xshift=-0.3cm]R.north) -- ([xshift=-0.3cm]I_2.south) node [pos=0.5,  
left] {$\varphi_1 R$};
                            %%% I_1--->R%%%
\draw[black,arrow] let \p1=(I_1), \p2=(R) in (I_1) -- (1.*\x1,1.40*\y1)node 
[pos=0.25,left] {$\gamma_1 I_1$} -- ([xshift=1.62cm,yshift=0cm]R.west) ;
                            %%% R--->S%%%
\draw[black,arrow] let \p1=(I_2), \p2=(S) in (R) -- (-2.5,-7)  -- (-2.5,0.25)node 
[pos=0.75,left] {$\varphi_2 R$}-- ([xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=-0.3cm]S.north) ; 
\draw [black,arrow] (S) -- (out) node [pos=0.75,left] {$\mu S$};
\draw [black,arrow] (E)(E.east) -- ([xshift=1.6cm, yshift=-3.5cm]out) node 
[pos=0.75,above] {$\mu E$};
\draw [black,arrow] (I_1)(I_1.east) -- ([xshift=5.5cm, yshift=-6cm]out) node 
[pos=0.75,above] {$\mu I_1$};
\draw [black,arrow] (R)(R.south) -- ([xshift=0cm, yshift=-9.3cm]out) node 
[pos=0.75,right] {$\mu E$};
\draw [black,arrow] (I_2)([xshift=0cm, yshift=-0.3cm]I_2.west) -- ([xshift=-2.2cm, 
yshift=-6.3cm]out) node [pos=0.75,above] {$\mu I_2$};
\draw [black,arrow] (out)([xshift=3cm, yshift=0.4cm]S.west) -- ([xshift=0.8cm, 
yshift=-0.6cm]out) node [pos=0.55,above] {$\Lambda N$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{FlowChart }
\label{fig:flow}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Here you can see the PDF of codes:
[image]